# Why does String.prototype.split return the full string

Tags: javascript, string, split, concatenation

Why does `String.prototype.split` return the full string if the string being split is concatenated?

```js
// Single line
var x = "foo,bar,boo,far".split(",");

// Concatenation
var y = "foo,bar," + 
          "boo,far".split(",");

// Output
document.write("<pre>");
document.write(x + " :" + typeof x + "\n");
document.write(y + " :" + typeof y + "\n");
document.write("</pre>");
```

In my actual code, the string is very long, and concatenated over multiple lines with the `.split(",")` at the very end.

So why would this result in the full string instead of an array as expected?

Answer (score 2):

The issue, as it turned out, was one of operator precedence. It didn't matter that it was on separate lines. What mattered was that the `.` and `()` have higher precedence than the `+`, and so the `.split()` was performed only on the last chunk.

So what was happening was this after the split:

```
var y = "foo,bar," + ["boo", "far"];
```

And because the array is converted to a string, and because the default `.toString()` simply joins the array using a `,`, we end up with this:

```
var y = "foo,bar," + "boo,far";
```

resulting in what looks like the original string.

Adding parens fixed this issue.

```
var y = ("foo,bar," + 
          "boo,far").split(",");
```

Comment: That's exactly it.